# Referring to architecture specific headers in cross-compile

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, cross-compiling, gnu

This question isn't specifically related to cross-compiling but has arisen as I have a problem related to architecture specific headers while trying to cross-compile a library.

I am trying to cross-compile OpenCV, the target is an ARM processor and I am compiling on an x86_64 processor. The build fails because a header file cannot be located:

> /usr/include/zlib.h:34:19: fatal error: zconf.h: No
>   such file or directory  #include "zconf.h"

Sure enough in zlib.h there is a reference to zconf.h:

> #include "zconf.h"

However when I look under `<path_to_arm_filesys>/usr/include` I actually find `zconf.h` under `<path_to_arm_filesys>/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf` directory. So as I understand it the C preprocessor won't find `zconf.h` as the reference to it **does not** include the reference to the architecture-specific sub-directory.

To try and understand how `zconf.h` is actually found, I referred to the host machine and where `zconf.h` is located. Similarly, it is located under `/usr/include` but under the architecture-specific `x86_64-linux-gnu` directory.

So if in the source code the is no specific reference to architecture (as to be expected) in any `#include` how does the (GNU) C pre-processor know where to look? Is it a case that the pre-processor already knows its architecture-target and can automatically append another architecture specific directory to all the include directories it knows about? Or must I specifically inform it with the use of the `-I` flag of these specific directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to say the compiler where to find headers :

- set the `--sysroot` option  #preferred for cross-compilation

> -sysroot=dir Use dir as the logical root directory for headers and libraries. For example, if the compiler normally searches for headers
>   in /usr/include and libraries in /usr/lib, it instead searches
>   dir/usr/include and dir/usr/lib.

In this case you must have all libraries and headers under the sysroot folder.

- Directly say with `-I` options where to find the headers.
- Set the `C_INCLUDE_PATH`/ `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` env variables

> For #include   preprocessor will seachy in search system directories and directories that were provided by compiler.
>
> For #include "filename" preprocessor will search in the same folder where you have file that have this include.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I'm getting confused how the C pre-processor interprets `#include` directives. For example I was thinking that for `#include "zconf.h"` is interpreted by the C-preprocessor as 'look in the ROOT include directory and there find `zconf.h`'. However as I there can be many 'root' include directories if one uses the `-I` option then which directory does the pre-processor consider as root?

Comment: I think therefore I must explicitly state the architecture-specific directory to include and NOT assume the pre-processor can automatically append an extra directory level (based upon the architecture is compiles for) to those includes it is informed of.

Comment: Please check my answer. By the way : if you are using compiler that was built with `--target=something` option, compiler may know about  `something` folder. 

Also it's easy to check which folders your compiler using just use `-###` option and see cc comandline